# Splitting elasticsearch timelion visualization based on prior query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I have an ELK stack I use for monitoring performance of applications. The applications create documents of the format

```
{"name": APPLICATION_NAME, "data": {"success": 20, "fail": 3}}
```

Where sucess and fail are the respective metrics for a time period.

I use timelion to visualize the performance of these applications with the query:

```
.es(split=name.keyword:200, index="logstash-*", metric="avg:data.success")
```

However, this gets difficult to view as the number of applications is huge resulting in a very dense graph.

I've been looking for a solution to "chain" queries together, for me to be able to say, filter by name.keyword for a time period if there was at least 1 document that had a success value of 0.

Most resources say that to prefilter data I should be adding an additional attribute to filter by, but I do not think that is relevant in this case.

Comment: The fist parameter of the .es function is the parameter q (for query), which is a Query String used to filter the data for this series. You can use 'AND' to chain queries together.

Comment: I was hoping to use the results of the first query as an input into the second query, as the first query will return name.keyword values that are relevant